constructor error while sending a post request (MERN)
TypeError: Class constructor ErrorHandler cannot be invoked without (new) or 'new'    at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
-- I have checked my all files very well and provided 'new' where needed. as far as i understand, according to this error i have to provide 'new' keyword while calling the constructor named 'ErrorHandler' but how when i am calling this in the middleware like (app.use(ErrorHandler).
I want my error resolved which is 'Class constructor ErrorHandler cannot be invoked without'.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
